# I'm trying to add a SSH key on GitHub however "Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format" keeps appearing

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, github-for-windows

I'm basically copying the following code into github from the linux terminal. Is there anything wrong with it?

ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDIlNTE5AAAAIKsxrHHSghWvO8MO+UlzmTHLxSp1BeuPX855Ywwdgi75 "my email"

It has 80 characters (except my email). How should I solve this? Thanks! :)

Comment: Looks fine to me... Does this key work elsewhere for you?

Comment: since I'm new to all this, could I perhaps know where else I could try the key out?

Comment: If you had a Linux server, you might use the same key to connect to it and it GitHub, for example.

Comment: So I assume this is the verbatim content of your `id_ed25519.pub` file, right? That *should* work...

Comment: Does it work if you leave off the third space separated part and just use the first two components (that is, just the `ssh-ed25519` and the base64-encoded part)?

Comment: Could this be that GitHub is preventing you from adding a key generated by some software with a security bug? I know that some while ago there were issues where OpenSSH (I think) generated bad keys (I don't remember in which way). What software did you generate that key with? What versions?

Answer (score 0):

I just generate an ed25519 key for testing (`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -P "" -f test`), and it looks like:

```
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAICKFNOBwj9d9fSEmG1jgouYbltgmRcYFHMkGN8QnuEoE vonc@vclp
# compare to yours
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDIlNTE5AAAAIKsxrHHSghWvO8MO+UlzmTHLxSp1BeuPX855Ywwdgi75 "my email"
```

The only difference is the email between double quotes, but I tried and add mine to My GitHub profile setting SSH keys, even with double quotes: it does work.

Your, however, does trigger "`Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format`", with or without the final email

So try and regenerate one: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -P "" -f test`: its test.pub content should work.